# How to only display 1 or 2 posts on homepage, if width 860px! (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post

I recently installed a theme for Wordpress, it's called Resi, and you can make posts as images - I have a suspicion that the size and the amount of images/posts I use makes Safari crash on mobile devices, so I was wondering if you could use a bit of jQuery to limit the amount of posts shown if the screen-width gets below 860px, for example. You can adjust the amount of posts shown in Wordpress general settings, but I was wondering if you can change that depending on the screenwith. I don't know how to achieve this. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly with CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could make 2 boxes. 1 box for larger screens, 1 box for phones and use CSS media to determine which box is shown.

Comment: Not really sure how to

Comment: @media screen and (max-width : 768px){
box1{
       display: none;
}
box2{
      display: block;
}
}